# When should ampersands entity (&amp;) not be used in HTML links?

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, html-entities

When should ampersands entity (`&amp;`) not be used in HTML links?

Context: The reason I ask is that I am using `DOMDocument()` to convert `<img>` tags to different HTML, and the ampersands are being duplicated.  For my specific example, I think it is happening due to `mb_convert_encoding()`, but if I don't use it, I have other issues.  Maybe there are other times one shouldn't use ampersand entities in HTML links?

```
public static function substituteImg($template, $values, $classI='autoInsert', $classF='',$escape=false) {
    $classesToReplace = array($classI);
    if($template) {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $template = mb_convert_encoding($template, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
        $doc->loadHTML($template);

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
        foreach( $xpath->query( '//img') as $img) {
            // get the classes into an array
            $classes = explode(' ', $img->getAttribute('class')); // this will contain the classes assigned to the element
            if (array_intersect($classes, $classesToReplace))
            {

                // preprocess the image name to match the $values keys
                $imageName = pathinfo($img->getAttribute("src"),PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                if (isset($values[$imageName])) {   
                    if(is_array($values[$imageName])){
                        //Not a text node
                        switch($values[$imageName]['type'])
                        {
                            case 'a':
                                $element = $doc->createElement( 'a',htmlentities($values[$imageName]['value']));
                                $element_href = $doc->createAttribute('href');
                                $element_href->value=htmlentities($values[$imageName]['attr']);
                                $element->appendChild($element_href);
                                if($classF) {
                                    $element_class = $doc->createAttribute('class');
                                    $element_class->value=$classF;
                                    $element->appendChild($element_class);
                                }
                                break;
                            default:{trigger_error("Invalid element type", E_USER_ERROR);}
                        }
                    }
                    else {$element = $doc->createTextNode($escape?htmlentities($values[$imageName]):$values[$imageName]);}
                    $img->parentNode->replaceChild($element,$img);
                }
            }
        }
        $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
        $template=$doc->saveHTML($body);    //Select the body tag 
        $template = str_replace(array('<body>', '</body>'), '', $template);  //strip the body tags
        unset($doc,$xpath);
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Sample array for passed to substituteImg()

```
Array
(
    [bla] => 2721930660
    [link1] => Array
        (
            [type] => a
            [value] => Yes
            [attr] => javascript:void(0)
        )
    [link2] => Array
        (
            [type] => a
            [value] => link
            [attr] => https://example.com/index.php?foo=123&amp;bar=321
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `&amp;` whenever you want to express the data `&` in HTML, except when you are using it inside an element where the content is expressly marked as CDATA (which means `<script>` and `<style>` elements).

**You should not *manually* use `&amp;` when you are using a DOM API to manipulate text in a DOM. (This is what you are doing here).**

If the DOM is generated from an HTML document, `&amp;` will be parsed to `&` when you generate the DOM.

If you generate HTML from the DOM, `&` will be expressed as `&amp;` when you convert it to HTML.

---

> For my specific example, I think it is happening due to mb_convert_encoding(),

No, it is due to `$doc->saveHTML($body);` which converts the DOM to HTML.

Comment: Thank you.  Very nice answer.  So, two times one shouldn't use `&amp` is within CDATA and when using DOM API.  Can you think of any other times?

Comment: Basically any time you are working with something that isn't expecting you to write raw HTML source code.